# How are activities determined?

Tags: rolemaster, rolemaster-standard-system

I'm currently reading the RMSS to get familiar with the rules.  Weapon Law and Black Ops are my new additions to Rolemaster at this moment.

In RMSS p. 73, Section 18.0, it specifically talks about activity in regards to movement.  I know that activities must be completely 100%.  If a specific activity takes up to 2000%, then it would take 20 rounds to complete said activity.

However, how do you really literally determine activity?  For instance, rappelling, placing breaching charges, kicking the door and storming a room, or throwing a grenade or leaning around corners?

Answer (score 3):

**You will want to cross reference section 25.0 Moving Maneuvers.**

> Moving Maneuvers include climbing, swimming, riding, stalking, *and any complex or unusual movement.*

(emphasis mine)

The general gist of the rules here is that the GM picks a difficulty for the entire maneuver.  Table T-4.1 gives some examples and Appendix A-1 expands on this in relation to specific skills.  You will want to look in these appendix since that contains a bunch of movement rates - why they put them there I do not know.  Check A-1.6 for some good info on standard movement rates.

The way I typically run it, the more the player wants to do in a maneuver the more difficult it becomes.  That increase in difficulty should be commensurate with the difficulty of the added action.  So if the added action by itself would have an Easy difficulty, increase the overall difficulty of the total maneuver by two steps.  This also applies if the wish to cover more distance than one might cover when moving safely / cautiously.

Remember too that if the player rolls poorly, they may not complete all their actions.  The result on that table is a percentage of the action completed, so have in mind how much each portion of a maneuver takes up from the total maneuver.  Conversely, if they roll well they may have some action left over.

Finally, this is a super flexible system, so the players can ask for the moon. It is OK to say to the player that any combo of actions or single maneuver is too much for one combat round.

Comment: If everyone is comfortable with it, it is a pretty cool system, in that it allows the players to attempt all kinds of shenanigans on the battlefield.  That can really make combat a lot more fun, and make buying skills really worth it.  Your job as a DM is to put fun stuff on the battlefield that the players can interact with.  Lots of chandeliers or rocky outcroppings.  Try setting a combat on several moving platforms to get a real feel for the system.  Boats going down a river, or on flying mounts.